# TypeError: player.b is undefined. How do I fix that?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

What needs to be adjusted in the code to fix that?

Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/0bnrg3k1/2/

```
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    const playerVars = player.b.b.playerVars;
    if (playerVars.loop && event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      player.seekTo(playerVars.start);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What more of the code do you need to see?

Comment: Can you please show me documentation on that please?

Comment: What exactly determines whether it is b.b, or g.g?

Comment: How did you know it was g.g and not c.c?

Comment: This is what I'm looking at: https://i.imgur.com/fwEOvH1.png / Where does it say use g.g?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `player.b.b.playerVars`, you need to use `player.g.g.playerVars`.

```js
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  const player = event.target;
  const playerVars = player.g.g.playerVars;
  if (playerVars.loop && event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    player.seekTo(playerVars.start);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I could not find the documentation, I debugged your code and found playerVars inside a g object which was in turn inside a 'g' object.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of that please so I can see?

Comment: What determines whether it is b.b, or g.g, or c.c, or r.r?

That would better help me to understand how that works.

Comment: In your ````onPlayerStateChange````. Insert ````console.log(JSON.stringify(event))```` as the first line. Copy the JSON string into an JSON formatter online and see the structure of event object. This might help in getting an idea about the event object